# CCMoveBy values on update()

Tags: cocos2d-x

This is my problem: I have a scheduled update, here I track the movements of my objects (sprites), I move them with `CCMoveBy`, and I need to constantly update the `zOrder`. For setting the `zOrder` I've made a `setZOrder()`, which it takes the actual position of the sprite.

And here is the problem, I get all the X and Y values **after** the object is in the target. I know I get the values after the object is in the new position because I've made a `CCLog`. I can read all the values from the sprite, only when it's in the new position, so everything is well sorted only when the objects are not moving.

How can I get the `CCMoveBy` values on every tick update? (or how can I get the `CCMoveBy` values in "real-time"?)

Here is an idea of my code.

```
this->schedule(schedule_selector(Game::update));

void Game::update(float dt)
{
   setZOrder();
   moveObjects();
}

void Game::setZOrder()
{
  //This function takes the X and Y position and the row and column where the sprite is. 
  //Is working good. But I'm getting the "move" action values, after the object is in place.
}

void Game::moveObjects()
{
   for (i=0; i < numChildren; i++)
   {
     CCActionInterval* move = CCMoveBy::create(targetPoint, time);
     object[i]->runAction(move);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do measures and move your sprite you need to use `CCSpawn` and `CCCallFunc` to call function that measures. Or even run some animation handler with `scheduleScriptFunc` method

Comment: Finally, I get it working; but with other method. However, I'm interested in your answer. How should I do the CCSpawn?

Comment: Create two or more `CCActions`, create `CCArray` and fill it with created CCActions, create `CCSpawn` with your array as a param and run through `runAction` like you did

Answer (score 1):

you can use `void update(float deltaTime)` function.

just active it in `initial()` function by `this->scheduleUpdate()` and the override `void update(float deltaTime)`.

```
bool Game::init()
{
...
moveObjects
this->scheduleUpdate()
...

}

void Game::update(float deltaTime)
{
// Do whatever
setZOrder();
}

void Game::moveObjects()
{
   // Here we move object and when they reach target, move then again , and ...
   // meanwhile in update() we are setting their Z Order
   cocos2d::Vector<FiniteTimeAction*> objectMoveAction;
   for (i=0; i < numChildren; i++)
   {
     ActionInterval* move = MoveBy::create(targetPoint, time);
     objectMoveAction.pushBack(move)

   }
   object[i]->runAction(CCSequnce::create(Spawn::create(objectMoveAction), CallFunN([=](){moveObjects()},nullptr));
}
```

I din't test above code and it may have syntax error. notice I use lambda expression and is works with cocos2d v3.x .

Good Luck =)